# Can I download Windows 8.1 onto my surface rt?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-rt

I would like to do this because windows rt. 8.1 does not support visual studio, and I need this to code my site and applications.

Is there a way to  upgrade to Windows 8.1 on my surface?

Comment: Windows 8 only works on x86-64 computers.  Windows RT only works on ARM hardware.  You have a computer with an ARM CPU.  What you want is not possible.

Comment: you need a Surface Pro to run x86 desktop tools or use RemoteApp (http://www.daveamenta.com/2012-11/using-remoteapps-on-surface-rt-windows-rt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really - Your 'real' issue is that there's no ARM build of VS, MS seems not to support anything but the default 'desktop' applications on the ARM based surfaces, and there's no practical way that you can run an x86 build of VS or Windows 8.1 on your ARM based tablet.

You're probably barking up the wrong tree with this approach, IMO. If you *must*, I suspect the only real way is to remote into a X86 based PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can also, if you have MSDN or Azure subscription, run VS on a Azure VM instance.  Scott Hanselman of Microsoft wrote a blog post on this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingASurface2RTARMToGetActualWorkDoneRemoteDesktopVisualStudioAzure.aspx